# tikzpicture cannot be centered after scaling axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, scaling

Using This MWE I get the plot I want, however it is not correctly centered above the caption.
I think the problem is the scaling, but this is necessary since without it the figure would be too small.

I tried all sorts of different scaling methods, but either they did not scale correctly or wouldn't let me center the figure as well.

How can I center the this correctly over over the caption using `\centering` ?

Using different values for the `xscale` shows the effect even better

Picture `xscale = 16`

[image]

````
\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,oneside,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,DIV=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htpb]
  \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=4, xscale = 16]

% Axes
\draw[very thick,latex-latex] (0,1.3) node[left]{$y(t)$}
    |- (0.6,0) node[below]{$t$};
 

% Plot function
\draw[thick,red] (1,0) node[left,black](s0){} -- ++ (0,0) 
    plot[domain=0:0.5,
        samples = 100,
        smooth]({\x}, {1*(1-exp(-(\x/0.1)))});
        
\draw[thick, dashed ,blue] (1,0) node[left,black](s1){}
    -- ++(0,0) 
    plot[domain=0:0.5,
        samples = 100,
        smooth]({\x}, {1});
        
        
\draw[thick, dashed ,black] (1,0) node[left,black](s3){}
    -- ++(0,0) 
    plot[domain=0:0.12,
        samples = 100,
        smooth]({\x}, {\x*10});
        
\end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Sprungantwort}
    \label{step_resp}
\end{figure}

\end{document}```
````

Comment: Quick fix: Add the option `use as bounding box` to the first `\draw` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes at `(1,0)`, s1, s2, s3, enlarge the bounding box. I don't know why you need them:

```
\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,oneside,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,DIV=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htpb]
  \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=4, xscale = 16]

% Axes
\draw[very thick,latex-latex] (0,1.3) node[left]{$y(t)$}
    |- (0.6,0) node[below]{$t$};
 

% Plot function
\draw[thick,red] %(1,0) node[left,black](s0){} -- ++ 
    (0,0) 
    plot[domain=0:0.5,
        samples = 20,
        smooth]({\x}, {1*(1-exp(-(\x/0.1)))});
        
\draw[thick, dashed ,blue] %(1,0) node[left,black](s1){} -- ++
    (0,0) 
    plot[domain=0:0.5,
       samples = 20,
        smooth]({\x}, {1});
        
        
\draw[thick, dashed ,black] %(1,0) node[left,black](s3){} -- ++
    (0,0) 
    plot[domain=0:0.12,
        samples = 100,
        smooth]({\x}, {\x*10});
        
\end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Sprungantwort}
    \label{step_resp}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I totally forgot those nodes, they are a relict used to label the graphs but are unnecessary now / need to be placed to the correct position. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Putting `use as bounding box` in the first `\draw` block fixed it as mentioned by [Jasper Habicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/47927/jasper-habicht)

MWE with fix

[image]

```
\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,oneside,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,DIV=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htpb]
  \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=4, xscale = 16]

% Axes
\draw[very thick,latex-latex, use as bounding box] (0,1.3) node[left]{$y(t)$}
    |- (0.6,0) node[below]{$t$};
 

% Plot function
\draw[thick,red] (1,0) node[left,black](s0){} -- ++ (0,0) 
    plot[domain=0:0.5,
        samples = 100,
        smooth]({\x}, {1*(1-exp(-(\x/0.1)))});
        
\draw[thick, dashed ,blue] (1,0) node[left,black](s1){}
    -- ++(0,0) 
    plot[domain=0:0.5,
        samples = 100,
        smooth]({\x}, {1});
        
        
\draw[thick, dashed ,black] (1,0) node[left,black](s3){}
    -- ++(0,0) 
    plot[domain=0:0.12,
        samples = 100,
        smooth]({\x}, {\x*10});
        
\end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Sprungantwort}
    \label{step_resp}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```